# I am trying to implement Firebase into my MAUI app but have run into a problem with the FirebaseAuthProvider

Tags: c#, firebase, maui

When I put the code in according to some of the ways the other people have implemented it, I get the error below and I cannot figure out why their code worked for Xamarin but mine will not other than perhaps the SDK has changed.

The `FirebaseAuthProvider` is being seen as abstract type when I try to implement it into my MAUI program and I am not sure how I would be able to change this at the moment and would love some help!

```cs
private async void LoginBtnClicked(object obj)
{
    var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebApiKey));
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///MainPage");
}
```

produces this problem:

> "Error CS0144  Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'FirebaseAuthProvider'  MysticsGuardian MAUI (net7.0-android), MysticsGuardian MAUI (net7.0-ios), MysticsGuardian MAUI (net7.0-maccatalyst), MysticsGuardian MAUI (net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0)  Active"

I have tried adding other nugets from Firebase to see if it would fix the problem of not being able to add the authentication part to my .NET MAUI app but it did not work.

Comment: Which specific nuget package are you using?  Which tutorials are you following?  If you are using MAUI why is this tagged with Xamarin?

Comment: Nugets: FirebaseAuthenticaton.Net FirebaseDatabase.net Newtsoft.Json
Turtorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGrh-z1G8lI
And because xaml in Maui @Jason

Comment: @Jason i dont know if it pinged because I edited it in

Comment: Did you add the *FirebaseAuthentication.Maui* package as mentioned in the documentation of the [*FirebaseAuthentication.Net* nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAuthentication.net)?

Comment: i dont believe i did let me look through this and gett back to you I've been looking for documentation everywhere so hopefully this helps @ewerspej

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the tutorial you shared, I could reproduce this problem.

If I installed nuget `FirebaseAuthenticaton.Net` with latest version `4.0.2` and nuget `Newtsoft.Json`,the problem will arise.

```
    var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(webApiKey));
    var auth = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(Email, Password);
```

But if I installed nuget `FirebaseAuthenticaton.Net` with version `3.7.2`, this problem will disappear.

And from [FirebaseAuthentication.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseAuthentication.net#readme-body-tab),we could find that the status of `FirebaseAuthentication.Maui` is `TODO`.

[image]

So Nuget `FirebaseAuthentication.Maui` feature in Maui should not be officially released yet.

And you can check the sample of the tutorial you shared [here](https://github.com/SyedMohsinAliZaidi/.NetMauiEmailAuthFirebase),the version of nuget `FirebaseAuthentication.net` used in the sample is `3.7.2`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply been a hectic week but thank you this worked like a charm!